# About js prototype

Tags: prototype

I can't use prototype and prototype function.
    Could give me some advice?

```
function ball( r , color , x , y ) {
this.r = r;
this.color = color;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

ball.prototype = {
    constructor : ball,
    drawBall : function() {
    var circle = new c.Shape();

    circle.setStroke(1).beginStroke(this.color).drawCircle( this.x , this.y , this.r );

circle.alpha = 0.3;
oStage.addChild(circle);
}


console.log(new ball( 24, "#fdef0a",396, 348).prototype); // underfined ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here, I assume you want to instantiate a new object and use it's methods defined in the object prototype?

I've made your code execute functions from the objects prototype now. Hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/h1jkotby/1/

````
```var basketball = new ball(24, "#fdef0a", 396, 348);

alert(basketball.constructor());
```
````

Comment: Very Thank your answer, i had sloved my question now , i am greenhand who to use the stackoverflow lately , Meanwhile I haven't a good english ability so .... can express my question clear . I want vote usefully for you however my reputation less than 15 ..... so very sorry for you help